# Is there a free Eclipse plugin that creates a UML diagram out of Java classes / packages?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, uml

This seemed to me like the easiest thing to find, a simple way to display my classes as UML in eclipse

But except this: http://java2uml.gforge.enseeiht.fr/ and this http://sourceforge.jp/projects/amateras/releases/ I haven't found any new, maintained and "good" implementation (with all due respect to the above two)

Anything else I've missed?

Comment: Look in eclipse plugin central. There are MANY UML editors there, and quite a few with round-trip model-code-model support for Java.

Comment: Yes, but which one? :) there are so many! the reason I've asked it here is to get a name of a mature plugin that was used widely

Comment: @EranMedan Did you find a tool to generate diagrams for code you've written? The tools listed below seem to be focused on generating UML diagrams from scratch and then generating code from the diagrams. I want the converse, which I believe is what you were looking for.

Comment: @MrMas to tell you the truth, I don't really remember if I found something or not, I simply ended up not using UML much unless needed by someone non technical, I found that writing class / interface stubs in code is good enough for peer developers when talking about design, writing an interface is faster, reusable, and readable, and I can change it fast without being dependent on an IDE or a plugin

Comment: You could try ModelGoon. I just installed it from the Eclipse Marketplace and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Did you consider

[Creating UML 2 diagrams with Eclipse UML2 Tools - Tutorial](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/UML/article.html)  ?

I had [older references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/390438/good-free-uml-tool-for-java-eclipse/390459#390459) for such tools, but the new ones are build upon UML2 project (described in the tutorial). [MDT-UML2Tools](http://wiki.eclipse.org/MDT-UML2Tools) is in the making, [Omondo](http://www.ejb3.org/) is there, but not free.
[Papyrus UML](http://www.papyrusuml.org/scripts/home/publigen/content/templates/show.asp?P=114&L=EN&SYNC=Y), for instance, is based on UML2 Tool.

There is a tool in the Marketplace that can do the above (UML Class, Package and Interaction). It's called [ModelGoon](http://www.modelgoon.org/). Last tried in July 2018.

The full list is available at [Eclipse marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/search/apachesolr_search/?filters=tid:19).

Comment: @VonC - I haven't found how to generate a Class Diagram based on existing classes, maybe I'm missing something, but that is not mentioned in the tutorial, and I haven't found how to do it after downloading and installing successfully the plugin

Comment: @Ehrann: if you are talking about Papyrus, the closest tutorial would be javascript:openWin('_popup','/home/liblocal/docs/Documentation/Java-Code-Gen/Papyrus-GenJava-Synchro-src2mdl.swf','1221','909','yes').

Comment: thanks, I ment the Creating UML 2 diagrams with Eclipse UML2 Tools - Tutorial. but I'll check Papyrus UML as well

Comment: Tutorial has moved to https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/UML/article.html

Comment: @Corporativo Thank you. I have edited and updated the answer accordinlgy.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to stay within Eclipse: use free [ObjectAid](http://objectaid.com/) - discovers parents, nestings, associations.  
If you want the tool, which in addition discovers and show children, usages, dependencies, annotations - then use free [Class Visualizer](http://www.class-visualizer.net/).

Comment: Jonatan, as an act of courtesy one could/should add a disclaimer to the answer when suggesting products, services etc one is involved in. This said, your Class Visualizer is definitely good. Thanks for it.

Comment: I don't think ObjectAid is free. Doesn't it have an evaluation license that expires in 2 days or something?

Answer (score 3):

I generally use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.org) to create documentation because it has **built-in support to generate inheritance diagrams**. There is an Eclipse plug-in for Doxygen called [eclox](http://home.gna.org/eclox/). It is not longer maintained since December 1st.

Doxygen is based on [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/). You could directly use [LightUML](http://lightuml.sourceforge.net/), which is based on Graphviz to create UML diagrams in Eclipse.

Comment: Tried getting LightUML but it depends on UMLGraph that seems to be offline

Comment: http://www.umlgraph.org/download.html

Answer (score 0):

Annotate your classes with Ecore's annotations, then you can import an Ecore file from them. You can initialize an Ecore diagram from them, or export it to UML, and initialize a class diagram from it.

Comment: Any link with a bit more detailed description of how to do that?