# UML & eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, uml

I have seen few UMl eclipse plugins,but I have nt find option to give project for UML diagram, which will generate class diagrams depends on oops relation to one class to other class,

can anybody tell me which plugin I use to generate UMl diagrams to my project ?

Comment: does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272591/is-there-a-free-eclipse-plugin-that-creates-a-uml-diagram-out-of-java-classes-p/2272664#2272664 help?

Answer (score 0):

If the question is to reverse the java code and create UML class diagrams then my recommendation is to use EclipseUML Omondo. This is very expensive but certainly the best.

You can also try Rational or Soyatec.