# Eclipse plugin for generating a class diagram

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, uml, class-diagram

What is a good Eclipse plugin for generating a class diagram (for a project)?

[This image right here](http://www.moparisthebest.com/downloads/rs377.jpg) is **exactly** what I'm talking about.

Comment: That's a class diagram. Is that what you meant by project hierarchy?

Comment: Uh, same thing isn't it? Regardless, whatever generates a picture like the one I showed is what I want.

Comment: not quite the same thing for professionals. Expect a few eyebrows when you use colloquial terms.

Comment: Well regardless, do you know of any plugins that do what I want?

Comment: This one: http://www.architexa.com/ looks very interesting.

Comment: The plugin "Papyrus" can help

Answer (score 148, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to state 'Class Diagram' instead of 'Project Hierarchy', I've used the following Eclipse plug-ins to generate Class Diagrams at various points in my professional career:

- [ObjectAid](http://www.objectaid.com/). My current preference.
- [EclipseUML from Omondo](http://www.ejb3.org/). Only commercial versions appear to be available right now. The class diagram in your question, is most likely generated by this plugin.

**Obligatory links**

The listed tools will not generate class diagrams from source code, or atleast when I used them quite a few years back. You can use them to handcraft class diagrams though.

- [UMLet](http://www.umlet.com/). I used this several years back. Appears to be in use, going by the comments in the Eclipse marketplace.
- [Violet](http://violet.sourceforge.net/). This supports creation of other types of UML diagrams in addition to class diagrams.

**Related questions on StackOverflow**

1. [Is there a free Eclipse plugin that creates a UML diagram out of Java classes / packages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272591/is-there-a-free-eclipse-plugin-that-creates-a-uml-diagram-out-of-java-classes-p)

Except for ObjectAid and a few other mentions, most of the Eclipse plug-ins mentioned in the listed questions may no longer be available, or would work only against older versions of Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you very much! Also, is there any way to have the plugin automatically get classes from one of my projects in Eclipse and automatically generate the diagram instead of me having to drag-n-drop the classes onto the diagram?

Comment: @Gnarly, ObjectAid does not appear to be capable of that, at the moment.

Comment: Darn! Oh well, this is excellent anyways. Thanks again.

Comment: @VineetReynolds - ObjectAid is not a free tool. Are there any free alternatives besides eclipse uml2. http://www.objectaid.com/install-license

Comment: You can drop entire packages with ObjectAid and the diagram will be generated.

Comment: I drop packages but I don't get neither classes nor relationships

Comment: ObjectAid website disappeared...

Answer (score 8):

Must it be an Eclipse plug-in? I use doxygen, just supply your code folder, it handles the rest.

Answer (score 4):

Try [Amateras](http://amateras.sourceforge.jp/cgi-bin/fswiki_en/wiki.cgi?page=AmaterasUML). It is a very good plugin for generating UML diagrams including class diagram.

Comment: It's not exactly what I'm looking for, but it's a very good option; Doxygen wasn't suitable for me, neither ObjectAid, the only weak point for Anteras is that you have to relate the entities by yourself, but appart from that, very simple and recommendable for **little** projects

Comment: its outdated now in the market

Answer (score 3):

Try [eUML2](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/). its a single click generator no need to drag n drop.