# Tool to create a diagrammatic representation of Java code / Get diagrams from code / Convert code to diagrams?

Tags: java, diagram, class-diagram, diagramming

I want a tool which will see my java code or eclipse java project and convert it into diagrams which show relations and dependencies between classes and methods. Such a tool would greatly reduce the need to explain my code to others. It will make the relevant diagrams/pictures which are much easier to understand than only comments and java 
docs.

Are there any reliable tools for such purposes ? I prefer free/open source tools. But, anything is okay as long as its accepted by the industry.

***EDIT***

I need all possible diagrams that one can think of - UML, Sequence, State, Interaction, Show which method calls which, etc. Its not a problem if each functionality is provided by a different tool. I can use multiple tools to generate different types of diagrams.

Comment: Look for an UML Eclipse plugin, it seems to be exactly what you need.

Comment: Probably the root issue is code with bad style. I would suggest to improve your code. Try to read some books, like Clean Code.

Comment: @defaultlocale - not really a duplicate because i ask about other diagrams besides UML.

Comment: @sp00m - I need other diagrams besides UML. See edited question.

Comment: @AppleGrinder Sequence, state and interaction diagrams are part of UML (UML isn't only class diagrams). UML Eclipse plugins probably all provide such features.

Comment: What's wrong with just using comments to explain your code. If it's well written it should be fairly self explanatory.

Comment: @AppleGrinder `Sequence, State, Interaction` diagrams are part of [uml](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Unified_Modeling_Language_diagrams). BTW, have you tried to google for something like: `state diagram for %IDE_NAME%?`

Comment: @Oleksandr.Bezhan - yes. sometimes my code is bad and i need to redesign and recode it.

Comment: @defaultlocale - UML2 tools cant be used for indigo. papyrus install failed, soyatec eUML2 failed, UMLet is unsupported. What do i do now ?

Comment: @AppleGrinder try something else? try to resolve problems? research a lil' bit? Generally these software thingies are extremely unreliable. If all of them fail one way or another then high-quality colored pencils and a good ol' ruler would be the way to go.

Comment: @defaultlocale - back to the stone age then. I will get my chisel and hammer to do the diagramming...on my iStone. :P

Comment: BinaryDoc is the tool can generate the UML and Dependency diagrams for Java applications. Here is an example (https://openjdk.binarydoc.org/net.java/openjdk/13.0/classfile?classfilelocation=java.lang.stringbuilder) for the diagram

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for are class diagrams. If you don't know what UML is, you definitely need to [take a look at it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Modeling_Language).

The question of generating class diagram with Eclipse has been extensively covered on SO, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302490/eclipse-plugin-for-generating-a-class-diagram) are good pointers for Eclipse plugins.