# Automatic creation of complete class diagram from Java project

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

Is there a solution for automatic creation of a complete class diagram from a Java project?

I've spent significant time looking online, trying Papyrus, Jar2UML, UML2Tools, DiaGen, jGraps, Class-visualizer, but have not found any currently working solution. Although most of the mentioned tools work (some do not currently work), they do not automatically generate a diagram of the full class hierarchy. I realise this might be the holy grail, and may require parameterisation, but thought it should be possible this day.

Requirements for wider use would be:

- Currently working
- Easy to use, or up-to-date tutorial on exactly how to do this
- Does not require manual coding
- Stand alone or Eclipse/NetBeans/IntelliJ plugin
- Free

If there is nothing like this available, I'm considering creating something like this.

Comment: What is missing when using the IntelliJ visualiser?

Comment: There is tools for this but they are not free. Some of them propose a free/community version with less functionalities so you maybe have to redo the missing functionalities.

Comment: Try Visual Paradigm, its free version is fully functional for first 30 days.

Comment: Questions starting with "Is there any" are regarded off-topic here.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, unfortunately IMHO these are not viable solutions (and a trial does not equate to free). As extremely similar questions have been posted here I do think this may be relevant to the coding community?

Comment: For completeness see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302490/eclipse-plugin-for-generating-a-class-diagram
(Fully support making stack overflow a more welcoming community - especially for non-experts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the fact I am not sure to have *all* the classes of a project into *one* class diagram is a good idea because the result is unreadable with lot of classes, you can do that for instance with my tool [BoUML](https://www.bouml.fr/index.html). After you download/install/run it :

- create a new project
- select Java in the global menu *Languages*
- for the first directory dialog appearing press the button *cancel* (you do not have a *java catalog*) then for the second directory dialog select the root directory containing all the sources of Java you want to model, then wait for end
- in the browser on the left in any of the created *class view* or in a new one you create yourself do a right mouse click and choose *New class diagram* and double click on it to open it
- probably you need to hide details of classes in the diagram to limit its size (you can do that later but better to do that right now in case you have lot of classes), in that case do a right mouse click into the diagram or on it into the browser to edit the *drawing settings* and set to *yes* the settings *hide classes attributes* and *hide classes operations* then confirm (button *ok*)
- use the button binocular on the top (near print button), change *kind* to *class* then use buttons *search* then *mark them* then *close*
- into the open diagram (shown into the right part of the window) do a right mouse click and choose *add marked elements* placing classes in random position then redo a right mouse click and choose *automatic layout* (you can also move the classes by yourself of course)

As you can see all the relations between classes are drawn, not only the generalization/realization. If you want only them without having for instance to hide all other relations one by one by hand you can develop a plug-out marking all the classes and generalization/realization of the model, then changing the procedure I given :

- when you edit the *drawing settings* also go into the second tab and set to *no* the setting *draw all relations*
- rather than to use the browser search (binocular button) to select all he classes use your *plug-out*

Anyway, again, to show all the classes into one diagram is a bad idea except if you have few.

In the page [documentation](https://www.bouml.fr/documentation.html) you have the reference manual and (old) video tutorials including the two ones dedicated to Java and an other one about to write a plug-out

---

Note you can also use [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) to make your diagram without using an UML modeler

Comment: Thank you bruno for your answer, I'm guessing there is an additional action between the 2nd and 3rd point, perhaps Tools -> Reverse Engineering Java? I did this, generating a populated hierarchy of my project, but when clicking/creating a new class diagram, it always shows empty.

Comment: @Yost777 yes you are right I missed the call of the reverse (funny). Of course when you create a diagram it is empty, there is no magic crystal ball to know what you want, the last two steps in the first list (*use the button binocular..* and *into the open diagram..*) mark all classes to place them into the diagram

Comment: thank you for elaborating - that works (also good to find that icon was portraying binoculars!) I was also able to get Doxygen working with GraphViz, though it only appears to visualise the directly connected classes for a single class. So, so far BoUML is the best option that indeed does the job including a fair amount of customisation, though it does seem for a complete class overview something better could be produced.

Answer (score 0):

Although BoUML does an ok job on this, for a large project it's not pretty.

For a better solution to fully automatically create a basic but complete class diagram from source code, try the simple extractor I put together in Java:
https://github.com/folterj/ClassDiagramExtractor

The project uses reflection, and produces a diagram from all the packages in a folder (and sub-folders).

Notes:

- No command line options - clone & run setting source folder in code
- This produces a gv file for use with GraphViz (dot), available here: https://www.graphviz.org/

The result looks quite good, as it groups packages together and even uses coloring.