# Is there any easy way to create diagram class from source code with reverse engineering?

Tags: java, uml, reverse-engineering, class-diagram

Is there any Eclipse plugin that extracts a Java class diagram with dependencies and hierarchy? I have tried several without success, for example: ModelGoon and Omondo I could not install them, ObjectAid and MoDisco showed a blank screen with no results, Papyrus shows the classes of a package but they are not linked to each other and does not show the subpackages of my entire application. I have seen that StarUML is a paid program and I don't know if there are other programs that do reverse engineering.

Can you help me? Thank you very much, best regards.

Comment: You may want to check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6302490/eclipse-plugin-for-generating-a-class-diagram

Comment: Sounds like you already found several, but you couldn't get them to work. I think you'd be better off choosing a particular one that definitely can do what you want (i.e. the tool's webpage says it can), and asking how to get it working.