# Free UML tool/plugin for Eclipse can generate Java code?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, uml

I'm newbie for Eclipse. I don't know what plugin can create class diagram, sequence diagram... and generate java code and of coursce, it's free. Anyone know some tools like this ?

Comment: Please, use the search ([Eclipse UML plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988384), [Eclipse plugin that creates a UML diagram out of Java classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272591), [UML Diagram Tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600097)).

Answer (score 1):

[eUML2 Free Edition gathers all basic features needed by java developpers and is free of use (even for commercial purposes)](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/features/)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use Togethersoft or Omondo for java but these tools are not free.

The only java free UML tool is eUML but it adds plenty of tags in my code. The generated code is a mess because the UML model is using @ UML directly in my java code. Both UML model and java code are therefore mixed mixed. 
If I refactor my code then all my model is lost. I only change one of my attribute and all my model was immediately lost. What was the worst is that I also lost my code which was changed. I needed to paste a copy manually all my classes and create a new project. I lost many hours of work just because I did create 2 small class diagrams !!
My code format has been changed without my permission. This is an unacceptable behavior. I like the tool but don't want that UML code generation be so intrusive in my java code. The graphical design is pretty nice but because this is live code and model syncrhonization and that the code is dirty this is a no go for me. It would have been good to separate live code generation from model and UML design like the other tools.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse, I suggest using eUML2 (http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/installation/).

If using Eclipse is not a must, I think the better choice would be https://www.magicdraw.com/ - they have a free version for students.

Answer (score 0):

[Topcased](http://www.topcased.org/) contains a UML editor together with a Java generator (and reverse).
The Papyrus Editor is included in Topcased.
They are both based on Eclipse Modeling Project.
Have a look on [tutorials](http://www.topcased.org/index.php?documentsSynthesis=y&Itemid=59).