# Creating a 4 + 1 Architecture model

Tags: java, eclipse, architecture, eclipse-plugin

Is there a simple way to create a 4 + 1 model from existing code? I was able to generate a class diagram from an eclipse plugin, but I can't seem to find a way to generate a package diagram. Is there a way to do this as well as the other views needed?

Comment: There might be an IBM product that does this, but it probably costs like 800$. For package diagram, check out any UML tool, like [objectaid](http://www.objectaid.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, there is no automatic way to generate all the 4+1 views from only the code.  You should be able to partially generate some...

- **Logical View** (partial reconstruction) -- This view is mainly concerned with functionality provided.  At a minimum you can use a reverse engineering tool (such as Rational Rhapsody but there are others, some open source -- [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272591/is-there-a-free-eclipse-plugin-that-creates-a-uml-diagram-out-of-java-classes)) to generate UML class diagrams.  Other diagrams will depend on tooling, programming language, etc.
- **Development View** (partial reconstruction) -- You should be able to generate package diagrams automatically.  You will not be able to automatically create an allocation diagram as the code will not necessarily tell you where it is intended to be deployed.
- **Process View** (no reconstruction) -- this view is concerned with run time structures.  Generating this is highly dependent upon tooling.  You might be able to generate some with Rhapsody depending on the code.
- **Physical View** (no reconstruction) -- this view is concerned with hardware or physical structures.  No way to derive this from the code.
- **Use Cases View -- the +1** (no reconstruction) -- scenarios of how the system is intended to be used to help validate design.  You might be able to derive this from any tests that exist... but you'll be missing the overall operational context which is kind of the point.

Typically to reconstruct the process view you will need to run and observe the system (or talk to someone who remembers how it was designed to function).  The same goes for the physical view -- you will have to dig through configuration and observe the running system to figure it out (or talk to someone).

Use cases view is going to be all interviews or inferences based on your observations and current understanding of the system.  The +1 scenarios are intended to frame the problem and be used for validation purposes.  If you assume the code is a true/correct/current reflection of the architectural intent (haha) you might be able to derive a starting point from the code -- but you will be missing the ever important answer to the question... why was it done this way in the first place?  And the answer to that question is kind of the main point of that view.